# LINQ to XML to read Hierarchal XML Document

Tags: c#, linq

I have an XML as an `XDocument`. How can I use LINQ to read an attribute x if SubMain y?

```
<Main>
 <SubMain Name="SubMain1">
  <Attribute1>Value1</Attribute1>
  <Attribute2>Value2</Attribute2>
  <Attributen>Valuen</Attribute2>
 <SubMain> 

 <SubMain Name="SubMain2">
  <Attribute1>Value1</Attribute1>
  <Attribute2>Value2</Attribute2>
  <Attributen>Valuen</Attribute2>
 <SubMain>
</Main>
```

Comment: Careful. 'Attribute' has a specific meaning in XML and that's not it. http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/dtd_el_vs_attr.asp

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty

```
            var xmlString = @"<Main>
                           <SubMain Name=""SubMain1"">
                            <Attribute1>Value1</Attribute1>
                            <Attribute2>Value2</Attribute2>
                            <Attributen>Valuen</Attributen>
                           </SubMain> 

                           <SubMain Name=""SubMain2"">
                            <Attribute1>Value1</Attribute1>
                            <Attribute2>Value2</Attribute2>
                            <Attributen>Valuen</Attributen>
                           </SubMain>
                          </Main>";

          var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
          var item = (from el in xDoc.Descendants("SubMain")
                      where el.Attribute("Name").Value == "SubMain2"
                      select el);
```